# on.exit() para regresar múltiples valores de una función en R. ¿Es correcto?

Tags: r, funciones, revisión-de-código, programación-funcional

Como saben, R es un lenguaje que, a diferencia de otros, no está diseñado para que una función tenga múltiples valores de retorno.

Revisando el sitio en inglés, encontré esta pregunta en la cual básicamente se habla de utilizar listas o, en su defecto, crear una función propia.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/how-to-assign-from-a-function-which-returns-more-than-one-value

Ahora bien, explorando funciones del código base me encontré con `on.exit()` que, según la documentación, registra una expresión dada como argumento para ejecutarse al finalizar una función. Según la misma documentación, `on.exit()` es útil en particular para regresar parámetros gráficos a su valor original o para otras acciones de limpieza.

Sin embargo, la propia naturaleza de `on.exit` nos permitiría añadir valores de retorno a una función.
Por ejemplo:

```
square_plus_four <- function(x) {
    on.exit(plot(df, type="l"))
    if(missing(x)){
    x <- c(1:5)
    }
    y <- (x^2)+4
    df <- data.frame(x,y)
    return(df)
    }

square_plus_four(1:10)
```

Esta función regresa, en una dataframe, el cuadrado de un número más 4 y además genera un plot para x y y.

Utilizando

```
on.exit(expr = , add = T)
```

Podemos agregar además otro tipo de expresiones que serán ejecutadas al concluir una función.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Sería `on.exit()` una alternativa válida para crear múltiples valores de retorno o es necesario ceñirse a las soluciones tradicionales como las expuestas en la pregunta a la que me referí al principio de esta publicación?

Agradezco cualquier orientación y comentario al respecto.

Comment: En general nunca he visto a los desarrolladores usar `on.exit`, ni tampoco veo una ganancia en usarlo. Por que enviar los elementos en una lista no sería una buena/simple alternativa?

Comment: No sé, pensaba que quizás usar on.exit implica pérdida de eficiencia de alguna forma o regresa resultados no válidos. Como comenté, su naturaleza permitiría utilizarla también como alternativa para regresar múltiples valores.

Comment: Puede ser relevante para ti tb este nuevo paquete zeallot, https://github.com/r-lib/zeallot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no es posible. Entiendo que lo que imaginas es que se pueda hacer algo como esto:

```
fn_prueba <- function() {
    on.exit(return(1), add=T)
    on.exit(return(2), add=T)
}
a, b <- fn_prueba()
```

o bien:

```
fn_prueba <- function() {
    on.exit(return(1), add=T)
    return(2)
}

a, b <- fn_prueba()
```

Estos ejemplos obviamente no funcionan, por dos razones:

1. Sintácticamente `a, b <- fn_prueba()` es erróneo. El operador de asignación [`<-`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) espera una variable del lado izquierdo y una expresión del derecho. Una única variable, que eventualmente podría ser una lista, con múltiples objetos, pero siempre una única variable. Es decir, ya de entrada el lenguaje no permite "recibir" eventualmente un retorno múltiple de una función.
2. El `return()` finaliza la ejecución de la función, ningún otro código se ejecutará luego del `return()`, por consiguiente tampoco podríamos definir un retorno múltiple ya que de cualquier forma el primer `return()` finalizará la función.

En otro lenguaje como **Python** es común hacer `a, b = fn_prueba()` para recibir dos objetos retornados por la función. Pero para ser honestos con **R**, no es más que un "truco" interno del lenguaje, la función en sí, retorna siempre un único objeto, en el caso de **Python** una tupla, que luego si, se permite "desempaquetar" en dos objetos, sintácticamente sería algo así `v = (1,2); a,b = v`

Estaría bueno que en **R** existiera este "desempaquetado", pero lo cierto es que no existe, por que el operador de asignación no lo permite. De forma que debemos hacerlo manualmente, algo como esto:

```
fn_prueba <- function() {
    return(list(1,2))
}

ret <- fn_prueba()
a <- unlist(ret[1])
b <- unlist(ret[2])
```

Volviendo a tu ejemplo:

```
square_plus_four <- function(x) {
    on.exit(plot(df, type="l"))
    if(missing(x)){
    x <- c(1:5)
    }
    y <- (x^2)+4
    df <- data.frame(x,y)
    return(df)
    }
```

La función no retorna dos objetos, solo retorna un `data.frame` producto de `return(df)` y realiza un `plot()` pero no lo retorna, tal como podrías hacer si hicieras `return(plot(df, type="l"))`. `on.exit()` tiene [muchos usos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300713/how-and-when-should-i-use-on-exit), pero el de retornar múltiples valores lamentablemente no.

Comment: Gracias, como siempre. Sólo comentar que no me queda claro a qué te refieres con que plot() no se retorna ya que al correr la función incluso solo como square_plus_four() aparece en efecto un gráfico, además de la data.frame en consola. Saludos.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, me refiero a que dibujar el `plot` es distinto a retornarlo en una función. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias. Como siempre, tus comentarios resultan de gran utilidad. Saludos.